# Placing intersections between two files into a text document

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have created a script that will compare a file of load balanced servers and compare it to a file of migrating servers to find the ones that will need new load balancing configurations put into place. I got the script to print to an output file but all the IP addresses are bunched together. I have tried the '\n' but I get the error message 'f.writelines(LB_Servers, '\n') takes exactly one argument' I gave 2. Can anyone point out what is wrong please?

```
 with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
     ME06 = set(open("LB_server_IP.txt").read().split())
     lb = set(open('mig_svrip.txt').read().split())
     LB_Servers = ME06.intersection(lb)
     uniques = ME06.difference(lb).union(lb.difference(ME06))
     print(len(LB_Servers), (LB_Servers,))
     f.writelines(LB_Servers, '\n')
```

Comment: `writelines` expects an iterable of strings. you're passing 2 arguments

Answer (score 0):

In python3 you can redirect output of print function to a file:

```
for server in LB_Servers:
    print(server, file=f)
```